# Forgot mongodb data path

Tags: mongodb

We have a mongodb database used for some years. Now the developer left. After server reboot, we cannot find out where is the data path he specified. It is not the default `/data/db/`. Our server is CentOS. Is there any command to search for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the shell and run the following command:

```
> db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts')
```

You'll see something resembling:

```
{
    "argv" : [
        "mongod",
        "--fork",
        "--logpath",
        "/data/logs/24rc2.log",
        "--dbpath",
        "/data/foobar"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "fork" : true,
        "dbpath" : "/data/foobar",
        "logpath" : "/data/logs/24rc2.log"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `dbpath` configuration line in  `/etc/mongodb.conf`.