# Recovering mongodb `--dbpath`

Tags: mongodb

I used MongoDB a month ago to run a simple web app to collect data for my research. After some inactivity (during which I did not run MongoDB), I forgot the parameter `dbpath`. Now, whenever I launch `mongod` on my Mac, I get the error, which I understand:

> Exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

I have tried:

1. Reading mongodb.conf (apparently that's not the correct path; I think it got reset.)
2. Looking into all my terminal history.

I do know the name of the collection and the database. And that my database was password protected.

I have already read most of the answers including this:

[Forgot mongodb data path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006703/forgot-mongodb-data-path)

Comment: This is really going to be related to your environment. You'll need to look at your local disk to figure out where your data files are (or look in the logs, which will give you this information). There's really nothing that can be done here (and it's not a programming question).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have already ran `find` on root directory. What kind of files should I be looking for?

Comment: @DaveIdito try to search for `WiredTiger.wt`.